# Converting saved_model to TFLite model using TF 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

currently I am working on converting custom object detection model (trained using SSD and inception network) to quantized TFLite model. I can able to convert custom object detection model from frozen graph to quantized TFLite model using the following code snippet (using **Tensorflow 1.4**):

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(args["model"],input_shapes = {'normalized_input_image_tensor':[1,300,300,3]},
input_arrays = ['normalized_input_image_tensor'],output_arrays = ['TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1',
'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'])

converter.allow_custom_ops=True
converter.post_training_quantize=True 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(args["output"], "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

However `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph` class method is not available for **Tensorflow 2.0** ([refer this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_savedmodel_)). So I tried to convert the model using `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model` class method. The code snippet is shown below:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/content/") # Path to saved_model directory
converter.optimizations =  [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

The above code snippet throws the following error:

```
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.
```

I tried to pass `input_shapes` as argument

`converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/content/",input_shapes={"image_tensor" : [1,300,300,3]})`

but it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: from_saved_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shapes'
```

Am I missing something? Please feel free to correct me!

Comment: TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model does not the argument `input_shapes`. The point is did you created your saved_model with `tensorflow2` ?

Comment: Hi, I have created the model using tensorflow 1.4. I have raised the issue on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35736

Comment: Should I have to convert `tensorflow1` model to `tensorflow2` model and then convert to `tflite` model?

Comment: I think that if you reload the model with tensorflow2, you can change the input_shape signature - though I haven't tested it

Comment: I am also not sure bcoz I am new to TF2.0 world. If I will find a solution than I will inform you. Thank you!

Comment: @edkeveked I got a solution and adding for the reference. Thank you!

Comment: Great that you solved it !

Comment: @edkeveked: Could you please guide me here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769698/how-to-use-ignore-class-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution using `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph`. This `compat.v1` brings the functionality of `TF1.x` into `TF2.x`.
Following is the full code:

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph("/content/tflite_graph.pb",input_shapes = {'normalized_input_image_tensor':[1,300,300,3]},
    input_arrays = ['normalized_input_image_tensor'],output_arrays = ['TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1',
    'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'])

converter.allow_custom_ops=True

# Convert the model to quantized TFLite model.
converter.optimizations =  [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()


# Write a model using the following line
open("/content/uno_mobilenetV2.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```